# Can windows operating system run 2 CLR's at a time?

Tags: c#-4.0

Consider one console application is created and running under visual studio 2005 and another console application is running under vs2010(CLR 4.0). Which CLR will run in 2 conditions?

Whether operating system will run 2 CLR's ? If not which CLR will run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have both CLRs installed, both can run at the same time.  The system will run one of the versions the app says it supports (which, in .net 2.0 apps, will be v2.0.50727).  It will prefer the latest version the app claims to support, but an app built with VS2005 probably will not run in 4.0 (VS2005 doesn't know to add metadata to allow support for 4.0).

Comment: is there any documentation available I can refer?